# regex help, accepting range of hex characters

Tags: regex, posix, posix-ere

I wish to accept hex characters only, case doesn't matter, so `[0-9a-fA-F]` but I only want to accept strings between 10 and 64 characters, what is the best way to do this range?

I am using POSIX Basic Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use quantifiers

```
^[0-9a-fA-F]{10,64}$
```

`w{n}` means match w n times **exactly** where n is a positive number

`w{n,m}` means match w **between** n to m times

`w{n,}` means match w n to **many** times

`^` is start of the string

`$` is end of the string

Now here `^`,`$` are essential else it would match anywhere in between

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I could have a range in the braces! Upvotes for all.

Answer (score 2):

You can give a range in braces.

```
^[0-9a-fA-F]{10,64}$
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^[0-9a-fA-F]{10,64}$
```